# Disable the minimize button in Internet Explorer IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I can use `window.open resizable=no` to disable/grey out the maximize button, but when I try to use `dialog=yes,minimizable=no` the minimize button won't grey out/disable, Please help me find a way to disable this minimize button, Thanks!

I want to apply this setting to a kiosk computer because I dont want user to minimize their browser and leave their credential open for the next person

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220056/disable-minimise-button-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

"Dialog" and "Minimizable" are not [valid options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You cannot, and should not, prevent a user from being able to minimize a window on their desktop.

If you wish to run the browser on a Kiosk, I would suggest loading the browser in [Kiosk mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780).