# How to disable minimize in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have thin client station, we are using Web Browser Control(the taskbar and start menu are disabled) Web Browser Control is the only option that user can access to the internet.Every thing is fine till here.But there are Particular Links in some pages where new IE window will open(Page will open in new ie window). If the IE Window is minimized the user's cannot see it. If there are 20 of IE7 minimized then the system hangs.

i cant use Kiosk Mode (iexplore -k). because user should allowed to close.

I cant change web pages.

But i Can inject Javascript(no Jquery) in to the Pages.

How Can i Hide/Disable Minimize, if i cant is there is any work around for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable the minimize button in Internet Explorer IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361025/disable-the-minimize-button-in-internet-explorer-ie9)

Comment: Kiosk mode? iexplore.exe -k http://stackoverflow.com